# Override default jquery ui library with newer version

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

The latest version of jquery ui core fixes a bug that's on my site. The problem is that Wordpress comes with an earlier version.

How do I override the default jquery ui core? One solution I've found is to edit the script-loader.php file in wordpress includes folder but I don't want to touch the WordPress core unless I have to.

Below is the core change that worked that I want to avoid.

```
$scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-core', '/wp-content/themes/themefolder/jquery.ui.core.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.2', 1 );
```

Comment: is it on the frontend or admin parts of your site?

Comment: the frontend of my site

Comment: Then you should contact the author of your theme before trying to solve it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code in functions.php file of your theme that will remove  default jquery ui core and will add your provided latest jquery ui core file from your theme.

```
function my_scripts_method() {  
 if(!is_admin()){     
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/jquery.ui.core.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.2', 1 );
}
}     
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Tell me if it works for you or i provide you another solution...

Comment: didn't work when I try to replace two jquery ui scripts.

function add_new_jquery_ui_core() {       
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', '/wp-content/themes/lastwell/jquery.ui.core.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.2', 1 );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog', '/wp-content/themes/lastwell/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.2', 1 );
}     
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_new_jquery_ui_core');

Comment: got these two errors

(1) Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'widget' jquery.ui.dialog.min.js:5

(2) Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Comment: Is it working if you only enqueue jquery-ui-core js and not jquery-ui-dialog.

Comment: Dont use relative path instead use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function.

Comment: I fixed it by added the correct dependencies for the dialog script.

function add_new_jquery_ui_dialog() {       
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .  '/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js', array('jquery-ui-resizable', 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-button', 'jquery-ui-position'), '1.9.2', 1 );
}

Comment: This is not an optimal answer as it will replace jquery ui for the site's admin which might break the admin once you upgrade wordpress.

Comment: and it will 100% break the admin if you change the active theme

Comment: @MarkKaplun I have changed the code to make it safe.